# How to empty cache in Chrome when it is frozen by an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to empty cache in Chrome to get rid of an old broken JavaScript but I am unable to do a hard reload or access the console because the browser is frozen from an infinite loop running in a script.

I close the window and open another one, but the site still loads the old broken JavaScript with the infinite loop and freezes again. (thus unable to do a hard reload or access the console)

How can I empty site's cache in Chrome when it is frozen by an infinite loop?

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're doing and what has gone wrong.  Also, please read **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up a new window, paste this into your address bar: (to access your JavaScript settings)

```
chrome://settings/content?search=javascript
```

Then disable JavaScript from:

[image: Chrome's JavaScript settings]

To clear the cache for that specific site:

1. Go to the site's URL
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> (Chrome Developer Tools)
3. Go to the **Application** tab
4. Click on **Clear storage**

[image]

Clear site cache and then enable JavaScript again.

Comment: I think I might have messed something else up. I just did a bunch of things including what you suggested and it worked. I also cleared all cache for the past hour, recompiled all js files in babel, and ended the process in the frozen window using `shift + esc` keys. I really should have done it all one by one and tested...